# __enter__ error using google's speech api python3

Tags: python, google-api, speech-recognition, gtts

I am making a speech recognizer project in python using google's API. The code is below:

```
from gtts import gTTS
import speech_recognition as sr

def get_audio():

    r = sr.Recognizer()

    with sr.Microphone as source:

        l = r.listen(source)

        said = ""

        try:

            said = recognize_google(l)

            print(said)

        except Exception as e:

            print("Exception: " + str(e))

        return said
get_audio()
```

And the error is:

```
<ipython-input-5-73a42a1f9208> in get_audio()
      1 def get_audio():
      2     r = sr.Recognizer()
----> 3     with sr.Microphone as source:
      4         l = r.listen(source)
      5         said = ""

AttributeError: __enter__
```

Can someone explain why? One person has the same code and that's running on his pc.

Comment: Is your microphone set up correctly? Can you save/record audio using Python?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
with sr.Microphone() as source:
   ...
```

Note the parentheses: it's a function call.